# Apache Beam: Error assigning event time using Withtimestamp

Tags: streaming, apache-beam

I have an unbounded Kafka stream sending data with the following fields

```
{"identifier": "xxx", "value": 10.0, "ts":"2019-01-16T10:51:26.326242+0000"}
```

I read the stream using the apache beam sdk for kafka

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO;
pipeline.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers("kafka:9092")
                    .withTopic("test")
                    .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
                    .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("enable.auto.commit", "true")) 
                    .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("group.id", "Consumer1"))
                    .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                    .withoutMetadata()))
```

Since I want to window using **event time** ("ts" in my example), i parse the incoming string and assign "ts" field of the incoming datastream as the timestamp.

```
PCollection<Temperature> tempCollection = p.apply(new SetupKafka())
                    .apply(ParDo.of(new ReadFromTopic()))
                    .apply("ParseTemperature", ParDo.of(new ParseTemperature()));

tempCollection.apply("AssignTimeStamps", WithTimestamps.of(us -> new Instant(us.getTimestamp())));
```

The window function and the computation is applied as below:

```
PCollection<Output> output = tempCollection.apply(Window
                .<Temperature>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
                .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                        .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(10))))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(1))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes())
                .apply(new ComputeMax());
```

I stream data into the input stream with a lag of 5 seconds from current utc time since in practical scenrios event timestamp is usually earlier than the processing timestamp.

I get the following error:

> Cannot output with timestamp 2019-01-16T11:15:45.560Z. Output
>   timestamps must be no earlier than the timestamp of the current input
>   (2019-01-16T11:16:50.640Z) minus the allowed skew (0 milliseconds).
>   See the DoFn#getAllowedTimestampSkew() Javadoc for details on changing
>   the allowed skew.

If I comment out the line for **AssignTimeStamps**, there are no errors but I guess, then it is considering the processing time.

How do I ensure my computation and windows are based on event time and not for processing time?

Please provide some inputs on how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use custom timestamp, first You need to implement CustomTimestampPolicy, by extending `TimestampPolicy<KeyT,ValueT>`

For example:

```java
public class CustomFieldTimePolicy extends TimestampPolicy<String, Foo> {
    protected Instant currentWatermark;

    public CustomFieldTimePolicy(Optional<Instant> previousWatermark) {
        currentWatermark = previousWatermark.orElse(BoundedWindow.TIMESTAMP_MIN_VALUE);
    }


    @Override
    public Instant getTimestampForRecord(PartitionContext ctx, KafkaRecord<String, Foo> record) {
        currentWatermark = new Instant(record.getKV().getValue().getTimestamp());
        return currentWatermark;
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getWatermark(PartitionContext ctx) {
        return currentWatermark;
    }
}
```

Then you need to pass your custom TimestampPolicy, when you setting up your KafkaIO source using functional interface `TimestampPolicyFactory`

```java
    KafkaIO.<String, Foo>read().withBootstrapServers("http://localhost:9092")
                    .withTopic("foo")
                    .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(Foo.class)) //if you use avro
                    .withTimestampPolicyFactory((tp, previousWatermark) -> new CustomFieldTimePolicy(previousWatermark))
                    .updateConsumerProperties(kafkaProperties))
```

This line is responsible for creating a new timestampPolicy, passing a related partition and previous checkpointed watermark see the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/TimestampPolicyFactory.html#createTimestampPolicy-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-java.util.Optional-)

```
withTimestampPolicyFactory(tp, previousWatermark) -> new CustomFieldTimePolicy(previousWatermark))
```

Comment: is it necessary to use this CustomFieldTimePolicy or we can use mapping after reading to assign timestamp , what's the difference ?

Comment: @zangw I have similar use case of adding custom TimestampPolicyFactory, the issue I'm facing is I can never get the o/p of groupby operation even when I start getting elements that are outside of the current window, which means the watermark ideally should have passed to next window

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a chance to try this using the time stamp policy, sorry I have not tried this one out myself, but I believe with 2.9.0 you should look at using the policy along with the KafkaIO read.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html#withTimestampPolicyFactory-org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.TimestampPolicyFactory-