# Apache Beam setting custom Event timestamp and watermark

Tags: apache-beam

I'm reading from Kafka using Apache Beam. I want to use the event timestamp from the payload instead of the default LogAppendTime due to out of order writes to Kafka.

I have seen a solution in 
[Apache Beam: Error assigning event time using Withtimestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216155/apache-beam-error-assigning-event-time-using-withtimestamp/54363103#54363103)

How do we define the watermark? Considering it should be monotonic.

In the method

> getWatermark(TimestampPolicy.PartitionContext ctx)

How do we determine the watermark when there is an event which is hours late.

This seems to be a very common scenario of out of order writes and event time windowing. I did not see much literature on how this.

Comment: Reading the comments of code makes me feel that watermark is a builtin machism in IO/Beam: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L523

Comment: The builtin uses LogAppendTime which is  monotonic. It will always progress forward even in case out of order writes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract timestamp from data using `ParDo` and `outputWithTimestamp` like its described here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements